# Get explain plan for query with inline function

Tags: oracle, functions, oracle-sql-developer, explain, oracle-18c

I have a query that has an inline function:

```
with function with_f(p_text in varchar2) return varchar2 is
  begin
    return p_text;
  end;
select with_f(dummy) from dual
```

Is there a way to get the explain plan for that query in SQL Developer?

I tried this:

```
explain plan for (
with function with_f(p_text in varchar2) return varchar2 is
  begin
    return p_text;
  end;
select with_f(dummy) from dual
); 
select plan_table_output from table(dbms_xplan.display());
```

But I get the following error:

```
SQL Error: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended
00933. 00000 -  "SQL command not properly ended"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The parentheses around the statement are wrong. It is

`explain plan for stmt`

and not

`explain plan for (stmt);`

---

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=589ff1ba836d6c28add25ee532221f33)